# Formatear fecha a español utilizando la libreria Moment js con Vue js

Tags: vue.js, momentjs

Estoy intentando formatear una fecha a español:

Tengo definido un método que recibe la fecha y lo formatea.

```
getDate : function (date) {
     return moment(date).format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a');
}
```

Y en la vista lo llamo de esta forma:

```
{{getDate(row.fecharegistro)}}
```

El resultado es este:

> January 23rd 2019, 6:23:18 am

Ya intente agregar **.locale('es')** pero aun asi no funciona

> return moment(date).locale('es').format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a');

Las librerias las tengo agregadas de esta forma

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: ¿Qué configuración tiene tu sistema operativo y tu navegador?

Comment: @fredyfx con configuración a que te refieres?

Comment: configuración de idioma. Porque el formato funciona bien, el tema va por el idioma

Comment: Lo estoy integrando con Codeigniter, creo que decargare el paquete de idiomas en español y probar.

Comment: ¿Tienes windows, Mac, GNU/Linux en español?

Comment: @fredyfx Si, en español

Comment: intenta con require('moment/locale/es'); esto para react muestra la fecha en el componente DateField en español

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No uses moment.js, usa [XDate.js](https://arshaw.com/xdate/) es mas ligero y mas fácil de configurar ;)

```html
<div id="date"></div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/xdate"></script>
<script>
XDate.locales['es'] = {
  monthNames: ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio', 'Julio', 'Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre'],
  monthNamesShort: ['Ene', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Ago', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dic'],
  dayNames: ['Domingo', 'Lunes', 'Martes', 'Miercoles', 'Jueves', 'Viernes', 'Sabado'],
  dayNamesShort: ['Dom', 'Lun', 'Mar', 'Mie', 'Jue', 'Vie', 'Sab']
};
var datetime = new XDate(Date.now()).toString("ddd, dd MMM yyyy - hh:mmtt", "es");
document.getElementById('date').innerText = datetime;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

En la documentación indican como configurarlo en español:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-moment#configuration

```
const moment = require('moment')
require('moment/locale/es')

Vue.use(require('vue-moment'), {
    moment
})

console.log(Vue.moment().locale()) //es
```